# Embed TikTok video in angular 9 Application

Tags: javascript, angular

on the tiktok developer page I've discover that is possible to embed a tiktok video in a web page.
The method seems really simple, copy the embedded code and paste it in your html code.

well, the code I've copied is this one

```
<blockquote class="tiktok-embed" cite="https://www.tiktok.com/@alebuffoli/video/6793667068622359814" data-video-id="6793667068622359814" style="max-width: 605px;min-width: 325px;" > 
<section> 
<a target="_blank" title="@alebuffoli" href="https://www.tiktok.com/@alebuffoli">@alebuffoli</a> <p>Non male ah? </p> 
<a target="_blank" title="♬ suono originale - Alessandro Buffoli" href="https://www.tiktok.com/music/suono-originale-6793595951710833413">♬ suono originale - Alessandro Buffoli</a> 
</section> 
</blockquote> 
<script async src="https://www.tiktok.com/embed.js"></script>
```

But the problem is that in a standard html page it works, but in my angular app the only thing I see is this:
[image]

But the result should be something like this: https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/Embed

I've even tried whit a `innerHTML` block, but the result is the same.
What's the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could place the tiktok's `embed.js` script in `index.html` file directly

```html
<head>
...
  <script async src="https://www.tiktok.com/embed.js"></script>
</head>
```

and then the HTML snippet in corresponding component's `*.component.html` file

```html
<blockquote class="tiktok-embed" cite="https://www.tiktok.com/@alebuffoli/video/6793667068622359814" data-video-id="6793667068622359814" style="max-width: 605px;min-width: 325px;" > 
<section> 
<a target="_blank" title="@alebuffoli" href="https://www.tiktok.com/@alebuffoli">@alebuffoli</a> <p>Non male ah? </p> 
<a target="_blank" title="♬ suono originale - Alessandro Buffoli" href="https://www.tiktok.com/music/suono-originale-6793595951710833413">♬ suono originale - Alessandro Buffoli</a> 
</section> 
</blockquote>
```